# Can I get a shortcut on home screen to open gmail with a specific search string?

Tags: gmail, app-widgets, home-screen-shortcuts, content-filter

I can add a shortcut/widget to home screen to directly open a particular label in Gmail app, but I want a shortcut to open Gmail with the results of a search string loaded.

I can't do this with gmail filter and a label because I intend to use `is:unread` in the search string.

So, is this possible? If so, How can I get this?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Correct casing is a pain on mobile devices ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not for the GMail app (on non root). If you are willing to use online, you may be able to use some sort of widget that links to the search query (just search it up and copy & paste).